# Add C file to Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. When I add files to my project, they have a `.cpp` extension. To work with C, I have to manually rename the files to `.c`.

Is there any way to directly add C files, without renaming anything?

Comment: See @Jason Williams post for the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to directly add a C file to the project. Unfortunately, I don't think VS provides any means to do so; you'll just have to rename newly added files.

---

You can rename a file from within the IDE. Right click the file and hit rename (or click on the file and push F2).

[Click file, push F2. http://blackninjagames.com/images/rename_file.PNG](http://blackninjagames.com/images/rename_file.PNG)

Comment: no  what i want is following for example we have getchar program   it's extension  is cpp  how change it to c?

Comment: @davit: I'm not sure what you're asking. A file's extension is in it's name, you're going to change it's name at some point one way or another.

Comment: c++ programs file is like this hello.cpp i want hello.c

Comment: @davit: Right, you just have to rename the file from .cpp to .c. I don't think Visual Studio provides a way of adding C files directly.

Comment: @davit: No problem, I'm actually surprised there isn't at least an "Add C file" option.

Comment: This is wrong answer. See @Jason Williams post for the right answer.

Comment: I agree with @dns - this answer should not be the accepted answer, as it is (at least partially) wrong.

Answer (score 5):

When you "Add New Item", simply include the extension in the "Name:" field and it will override the default for the selected file type.

Comment: Very straight forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I've created new item template (add **C File Plugin**),

You can download: [Visual Studio - New Item Template.zip](https://bitbucket.org/SiraitX/various-c-library-miscellaneous-projects/downloads/Visual%20Studio%20-%20New%20Item%20Template.zip)

Extract the ZIP file to:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates\
```

or (for VS2012):

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C++ Project
```

or if you want to put it under "**Code**" sub category:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C++ Project\Code
```

Or you can read this [Tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/780/visual-studio-how-to-create-item-templates) to create custom **item template** for Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: Using VS2013, I extracted the 4 files into the mentioned directory, but see no change in the "Add New item" dialog. Is a restart required? The other items in that folder are subdirectories with project type names. Shouldn't your template be set inside a subdirectory?

Comment: OK, looks like I just needed to restart my VS. I now have a .c file option.

Comment: 1. I moved the files into the `Visual C++ Project` folder and it works fine.

Comment: 2. You may want to change the `<DefaultName>C File (.c).c</DefaultName>` line to `<DefaultName>Source.c</DefaultName>`, to be more in-line with the .cpp file names.

Comment: 3. The icon does not match the VS2013 theme, but this is not a big deal.

Comment: HUH?? This looks like something very stupid is happening - after some playing around with your template and repeatedly restarting the VS2013, I now get a message of "Initializing templates" when I try to add a new item, and the new file type does not appear anymore. Reverting to the original (your) template file did not help... What's going on here?

Comment: OK, looks like I had to keep the files in teh *.zip archive, rather than extract the individual files to the templates directory.

Comment: 4. The file type does not appear in the `Code` section under `Visual C++`. I tried modifying the `SubType=""` field to `SubType="Code"`, but it did not help.

Comment: I works on my VS2012 Ultimate & VS2013 Express. You can see the screenshot, there's a new item "add C File".

Comment: Your template works great (and got an upvote), but my last comment referred to seeing the C type under the "Code" section. In your image, you are at the top level ("Visual C++"). Try to click on the "Code" category. On my VS2013, there is only ".cpp" and ".h". Also, if you notice your "Name:" field in the image, you'll see that it contains the description as the default filename, while it should be "Source.c", like in the C++ type (as I mentioned in the 2nd comment).

Comment: You can put under "Code" by creating new directory called "Code" and then Copy the zip file there. You also can change the default name to "Source.c" by changing to <DefaultName>Source.c</DefaultName> .
I've updated the ZIP file & screenshot, you can try it from the download link above.

Comment: You also can change the default "C" icon by replacing the PNG file inside the ZIP file.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the default name change is what I did as described in comment #2. I also figured out how to change the icon, but thought it would serve as a constructive feedback for you. Apparently, the new file type appears *only* in the category where the zip file is located. So, to keep the "C" entry in both places, I had to duplicate the zip file in the "Code" directory. All-in-all - great job!

Answer (score 3):

Just add a text file and specify the extension to be .C

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried this, but you can probably [create a Template](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/visual-studio-how-to-create-item-templates) that causes the new file to be named with a .c extension by default: