# How do I add a new C file in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, ide

I am new to Visual Studio 2013, having used 2010 in the past. How do I add a C file? There only seems to be an option for C++. I do not use C++, only C, and I compile to ANSI C99. This is what the dialog box looks like when I pick "Add New Item":

[image: Visual Studio Add New Item]

As you can see it has choices to add a C++ file or a header file, but not a C file.

Comment: Can you add a new template, as you can do in VS 2010?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368798/add-c-file-to-visual-studio

Comment: simply change the file name to have a '.c' extension rather than a '.cpp' extension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add C file to Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368798/add-c-file-to-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the file to the solution, right-click on it, and in 
C/C++->Advanced->Compile As, click on Compile as C Code (/TC)

Renaming the file is not enough, you need to tell Visual Studio 2013 is a C file. Visual Studio 2013 does not support the C99 standard, but at least it will be using C ABI and you will restrict the compiler to accept C statements only.

Visual Studio 2015 fully implements the C99 Standard Library, with the exception of any library features that depend on compiler features not yet supported by the Visual C++ compiler (for example, `<tgmath.h>` is not implemented).

[image: Visual Studio 2013 C/C++ Advanced options]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

Visual C++ is a C++ IDE backed by a C++ compiler.  It supports the common subset of C and C++ (because it is also valid C++), but does not directly support C.  It only partially supports C99.  So there is no way to add a file that will be compiled as C99 to a project.

Comment: Related blog post : http://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/

Answer (score 1):

this link: http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/tali/E15/Visual_C.html
may be helpful.

Here is what that link says:

Using Microsoft Visual Studio for Simple C Programs

A free version of Microsoft Visual C++ Express is available in: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/express/aa700735.aspx

To edit your C program:

```
From the main menu select File -> New -> Project
In the New Project window:
Under Project types, select Win32 - Win32 Console Application
Name your project, and specify a location for your project directory
Click 'OK', then 'next'
In the Application Wizard:
Select Console application
Select Empty project
Deselect Precompiled header
Once the project has been created, in the window on the left hand side you should see three folders:
Header Files
Resource Files
Source Files
Right-click on Source Files and Select Add-> New Item
Select Code, and give the file a name
The default here will be a file with a *.cpp extension (for a C++ file). After creating the file, save it as a *.c file.
```

To compile and run:

```
Press the green play button.
By default, you will be running in debug mode and it will run your code and bring up the command window.
To prevent the command window from closing as soon as the program finishes execution, add the following line to the end of your main function:
getchar();
This library function waits for any input key, and will therefore keep your console window open until a key is pressed.
```

Comment: Renaming the file to `foo.c` doesn't really do anything; it still gets compiled as C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **new item template** (add **C File** plugin),

You can download: [Visual Studio - New Item Template.zip](https://bitbucket.org/SiraitX/various-c-library-miscellaneous-projects/downloads/Visual%20Studio%20-%20New%20Item%20Template.zip)

Extract the ZIP file to:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates\
```

or (for VS2012):

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C++ Project
```

or if you want to put it under "**Code**" sub category:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C++ Project\Code
```

Or you can read this [Tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/780/visual-studio-how-to-create-item-templates) to create custom **item template** for Visual Studio.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use Visual Studio to create C programs. You can edit an existing simple C program by creating a new project, selecting Win32 console application, add in the existing files and modify it from there. But there is no from-scratch C support. See [related](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/tali/E15/Visual_C.html) for more detail on how to do it.